# Photoshop Action Script

Tags: action, photoshop

I need to do a batch image converter. I need to convert tiff files to rgb files. some of the tiff files are saved differently ( have layers ). I already have a script to convert that but I now have a problem where I will get a message saying an " Unknown data has been encountered reading layer ... " when it opens some of the tiff files. I will need to select 1 of the option before it will continue running the automated batch process with the script that I had setup.

I wish to be abler to skip or write a script to auto-select the option. Basically I just want it to keep running and not stop when there is a message when it opens the tiff file.

Comment: More information would be useful. What does the script do? What option needs to be chosen? Can the choice be integrated in the script? etc...

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59787382/edit) instead of adding information in comments